# Solucionar vulnerabilidades angular

Tags: angular, npm

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WlOs.png]

Como se observa en la imagen cada vez que quiero instalar con `npm` o ejecutar un comando para alguna dependencia siempre sale este mensaje , hay alguna sugerencia para que no vuelvan a salir estas vulnerabilidades o que me deje instalar ?  agradezco mucho cualquier orientación.

Comment: Son avisos (warnings) diciéndote que algunas dependencias que usas tienen bugs conocidos y que deberías actualizarlas, pero la instalación se ha realizado

Comment: Si quieres saber cuáles son las vulnerabilidades ejecuta `npm audit` y te dará el detalle.

Comment: disculpame la ignoracia como puedo actualizar esas dependencias?  `npm update`?

Comment: en el texto te lo pone: `npm audit fix`

Comment: Leyendo en detalle lo que te devulve el error, y haciendo [una búsqueda generalizada](https://www.google.com/search?q=npm+solucionar+vulnerabilidades&oq=npm+solucionar+vulnerabilidades&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2.12608j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) se suelen encontrar soluciones a este tipo de problemas. Te paso [uno de los enlaces](https://www.todojs.com/npm-audit-avisa-de-vulnerabilidades/) que salen de la búsqueda general que te puede valer

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que sigas estos pasos para hacer una actualización segura de tus dependencias(sobre todo al usar `npm audit fix --force`)

1. Haz un commit con los cambios actuales. Puedes usar `git add --patch .`  y/o si creaste nuevos elementos que no has enviado antes usa `git add .` . Y por último haz `git commit -m "Tu mensaje de comit.`

   - En caso de que los cambios no esten listos para el commit  puedes hacer uso de `git stash` para dejar tu rama limpia temporalmente.
2. Crea una nueva rama  `git branch front_actualizacion`.
3. Cambia de rama con `git checkout front_actualizacion`
4. Ejecuta `npm audit fix`
5. Si aun hay vulnerabilidades que tienen "breaking changes" (cambios que rompen tu código) ejecuta `npm audit fix --force`
6. Si todo sale bien, testea que angular se levanta correctamente y haz un commit de los cambios. Ejemplo : `git add . && git commit -m "fix: Actualizaciones de seguridad"`
7. Cuando valides que todo funciona bien, cambia de rama con `git checkout front` y haz un merge de los cambios con `git merge front_actualizacion`
8. Por último, si hiciste `git stash` es necesario hacer ahora `git stash pop` para obtener de nuevo los cambios en la rama actual y seguir trabajando con ellos.

- Puedes eliminar la rama creada con `git branch -d front_actualizacion`

Y listo!!